# matplotlib: quiver plot scaling for large vector range

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a dataset with a relatively large range of values for vectors which I'm plotting using matplotlib's quiver() function. The range can reasonably be up to 2 orders of magnitude (10 up to 1000), but the high end could be even a bit higher.

The problem I have is I can't find the right scaling options to create a reasonable looking quiver plot. I've tried both using the quiver plot **kwargs ('scale', 'units', and 'scale_units'), as well as normalizing and/or scaling the actual data, but I can't see to find anything that makes sense given I don't know the actual range of the inputs beforehand.

A very simplistic example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.quiver((100, 75, 50), (100, 100, 100), (0, 0, 0), (1000, 100, 10), scale_units='xy', scale=1)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.grid(True)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax2.quiver((100, 75, 50), (100, 100, 100), (0, 0, 0), (1000, 100, 10), scale_units='xy', scale=None)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.grid(True)
ax.set_title('scale=1')
ax2.set_title('scale=None')
plt.show()
```

The example simply demonstrates 2 of the available scaling options in quiver(), but as you can see on the left plot the largest forces are way off the plot, while in the right plot the smaller forces aren't even visible on the plot.

Anyone have a suggestion on how to set the scaling here without knowing beforehand what the range of actual user inputs will be?

If it helps, the locations are in inches from a known point and are likely in the range of 36"-200", while the vectors are forces which as stated before could be anywhere from 10lbf to 1000lbf or so.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe taking the logarithm of the vector length, like `ax.quiver((100, 75, 50), (100, 100, 100), (0, 0, 0), np.log((1000, 100, 10)))`?

Comment: Taking the log is actually an elegant solution except for one thing. The inputs for U and V are vectors built from user inputs of forces. This means the user could input U=0 or V=0 for any entry (this would be a force purely in an X or Y direction in this case). This would require some other kind of processing to either ensure there are no 0s in the vector (unlikely) or only apply the log to the non-zero elements of the vector. Thoughts on an equally elegant way to do this? Possibly something using list comprehension?

Comment: Maybe just adding `1`, like `np.log(np.array(V)+1)`.